pandasGUI Grapher does not render images (under windows 10)
The grapher in pandasgui does not work: the image does not render. Neither empty axes, nor any graphs with data.
picture of the problem
System: Windows 10
Python 3.9.2
Code Editor: VSCode
pandas (Version: 2.2.2)
numpy (Version: 1.26.4)
PyQt5 (Version: 5.15.10)
PyQt5-sip (Version: 12.13.0)
PyQtWebEngine (Version: 5.15.6)
plotly (Version: 5.20.0)
wordcloud (Version: 1.9.3)
appdirs (Version: 1.4.4)
pynput (Version: 1.7.6)
IPython (Version: 8.18.1)
pyarrow (Version: 15.0.2)
astor (Version: 0.8.1)
typing-extensions (Version: 4.9.0)
qtstylish (Version: 0.1.5)
Do you have any idea how to solve it?
I already have done:
$env:QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS = "--enable-logging --log-level=3 --no-sandbox" on the terminal but it did not work. I use a virtual env. Thank you!
